# Get text from radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with three radio buttons. I want the user to be able to select any of the radio buttons and selected radio button value should appear in `div` with  and id of `test`. For example if the radio with a value of 'Male' is selected, then 'Male' should appear.

Here is the code I have:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
    </div>
    <div id="test" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 80px; height: 30px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `change` event of the radio buttons, and on change, read the value of the checked radio button.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $('#test').text($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</div>
<div id="test" style="border:1px solid black; width: 80px; height: 30px;"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, it works!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but here's my contribution:

Used jQuery [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event to detect the change of the radio button and used [`e.target.value`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to get the value of the current radio button.

---

```js
$('#test').text($('input[checked]').val());
$('input[type=radio][name=gender]').change(function(e) {
 $('#test').text(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio_buttons">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</div>
<div id="test" style="border:1px solid black; width: 80px; height: 30px;"></div>
```

Comment: This is so awesome! Thanks mate :)

Comment: The initial contents of the `test` div are `other` even if `male` was checked.

Comment: It was a weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

**In vanilla JavaScript:**

First, you'll want to assign variables for each element.

```
var maleInputEl = document.querySelector("[value=male]");
var femaleInputEl = document.querySelector("[value=female]");
var otherInputEl = document.querySelector("[value=other]");
var testEl = document.getElementById("test");
```

Next, you'll add a value variable to store the currently selected value and add event listeners to each input to listen for a click.

```
var value;

maleInputEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    value = maleInputEl.value;
    insertText(value);
});

femaleInputEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    value = femaleInputEl.value;
    insertText(value);
});

otherInputEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    value = otherInputEl.value;
    insertText(value);
});
```

Last, you'll want to insert that text using the `insertText()` function.

```
function insertText(val) {
    testEl.innerText = val;
}
```

There are many different, and probably more efficient, ways to achieve this effect, but this should get you started.